# asking user for input and getting it from the terminal in c using getchar()

Tags: c

I am trying to ask a user for a string of input and then get that input from the terminal. Here is my code but it is not working(it doesn't ask user for input).

```
printf("Enter search string or X to exit:\n");
char str[1024] = " ";
   char h;
   int j = 0;
   while( (h = getchar()) != '\n'){
   str[j++] = h;
   str[j] = '\0';
}
```

Should be giving a user input

Comment: Did you read the documentation of ```getchar```, it's return value, and why it should be ```int h``` instead of ```char h```?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "not working". If you don't see the prompt, and you run your program on a non-standard terminal device (for example, from within some IDEs), you may need to add a call to `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`. Also be aware that `getchar` returns `int` rather than `char`, and there is a reason for it. Use `int h` instead of `char h`.

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent `fgets()`?

Comment: `int h;` and `while((h = getchar()) != '\n' && h != EOF) { ... }`. You can also move `str[j] = 0;` after you exit the loop.